# Using foreach loop to iterate through two lists

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists

```
List<object> a = new List<object>();
List<object> b = new List<object>();
```

Now i want to iterate through the elements of both list. I could do that by writing a foreach loop for each list. But is it also possible to do something like that?

```
foreach(object o in a, b) {
 o.DoSomething();
}
```

It would also be nice if something like that would be possible:

```
foreach (object o in a && b) {
   o.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to iterate through them simultaneously, or first one then the other?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
foreach(object o in a.Concat(b)) {
 o.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if Concat is not supported by the Collection i use?

Comment: If you are using a List<T> and .Net version 3.5 or higher you do have the `Concat` method. Just add `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 15):

If you want to iterate through them individually then you can use `Enumerable.Concat` as has already been pointed out.

If you want to iterate over both lists simultaneously, having access to one element from each inside your loop, then in .NET 4.0 there is a method [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) that you can use.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);

foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Result:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach(object o in a.Concat(b)) {
 o.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way you could do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (a.Count > b.Count ? a.Count : b.Count); i++)
{
    object objA, objB;
    if (i < a.Count) objA = a[i];
    if (i < b.Count) objB = b[i];

    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: instead of `(a.Count > b.Count ? a.Count : b.Count)` you can use `Math.Max(a.Count, b.Count)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simultaneously iterate over two Lists of the same length (specially in the scenarios like comparing two list in testing), I think for loop makes more sense:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++) {
    if (list1[i] == list2[i]) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply we can achieve using for loop**

```
 int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
    
     for (int i = 0; i < numbers .Count; i++)
                {
    var list1=numbers [i];
    var list 2=words[i];
    }
```