# How to loop through two lists simultaneously?

Tags: vb.net, list, foreach

I have referred to the following question at: [Using foreach loop to iterate through two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450650/using-foreach-loop-to-iterate-through-two-lists). My question is this, with regards to the chosen answer: Can the o.DoSomething be a comparison? As in:

```
For Each a in ListA.Concat(ListB)
    If(a from ListA=a from ListB) Then
        Do Something here
    End If
Next
```

As you might've guessed, I'm using VB.Net and would like to know how I can do what I have shown here. That would basically be to iterate through a joined list separately/independently. Thanks!

Comment: @Dean: There's nothing there that I can use. It's too complicated and I'm using .Net 4 now. Zip would've worked, but how do I set the condition there? Also, I'm using Lists, not IEnums. Can you please let me know the right way of doing this?

Comment: Bear in mind that to act on the IEnumerator(Of ListA) all you need to do is call ListA.GetEnumerator() (for both lists obviously). I have added an edit to illustrate how you can possibly use Zip

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but I realised that I didn't need to this at all. I went about solving the issue in a different way. Thanks a lot though! Learnt a lot in the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question indicates that you need a `Join` operation, because it's not that you want to iterate over two lists, but you also want to match like items from one list to the other.

```
    Dim joinedLists = From item1 In list1 _
                    Join item2 In list2 _
                    On item1.Bar Equals item2.Bar _
                    Select New With {item1, item2}

    For Each pair In joinedLists
        'Do work on combined item here'
        'pair.item1'
        'pair.item2'
    Next
```

Other answers recommend `Zip`. That is simply a function that takes two sequences and produces a single result, much like join, but it is geared to work in a FIFO method over both lists. If you need connections made based on an equality, `Join` is the specifically built to be right tool for this job.

Comment: +1 This is correct provided you want every possible combination to be tested for equality, rather than only combinations at matching index positions in the two lists. I can't decide from the question which is wanted. E.g. Should `{0, 1, 2}` and `{2, 0, 1}` report no matches or three matches? Your answer reports three matches 0=0 1=1 and 2=2. @Akshay, which do you want?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to my question [is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-two-ienumerable-objects-at-the-same-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981867/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-two-ienumerable-objects-at-the-same-time) may help

```
  Dim listA As List(Of A)
            Dim listb As List(Of B)

            listA.Zip(listb, Function(a, b) a.property1 = b.property1).ForEach(AddressOf Print)   


Shared Sub Print(ByVal s As A)
    Console.WriteLine(s.Property1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using nested for each as of now, but its not working out too well..:( Will try Zip and see..

Comment: Thanks! :) Will try this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: So that will return an IEnumerable of Booleans indicating whether each pair is equal? What about the "do something here" part of the question? How will you "do something here"?

Comment: You could potentially use a .ForEach(Action(Of T) at the end of this to assign a delegate to carry out the 'Do Something' I have updated the sample to give you a rough idea, however I get the feeling that carrying out the manual looping using the GetEnumerator() method in my link may be they way forward for you here.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 4 you could use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx). Adapted from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474536/is-there-a-way-to-loop-over-multiple-variables-in-a-for-each-loop-in-vb-net) from a Python fan specifically asking for [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387036.aspx) - you could remove the tuples if you like.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arr1() As String = {"a", "b", "c"} '' will also work with Lists
    Dim arr2() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}
    For Each t In TupleSequence(arr1, arr2)
        If t.Item1 = t.Item2 Then
          '' Do something
        End If
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Function TupleSequence(Of T1, T2)(
    ByVal seq1 As IEnumerable(Of T1),
    ByVal seq2 As IEnumerable(Of T2)
    ) As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of T1, T2))
    Return Enumerable.Zip(seq1, seq2, 
      Function(s1, s2) Tuple.Create(s1, s2)
    )
End Function
```

Comment: I tried Zip, but how do I specify the equality condition? If you can give me the syntax, I'd love to try that. Tried something on my own. Didn't work. Any help?

Comment: @Akshay Isn't it in my answer? `If t.Item1 = t.Item2 Then Do Something [with t.Item1 or t.Item2, presumably doesn't matter which one you use if they are equal]`

Answer (score 0):

On solution would be to have a dictionary with items from the second list, then loop through your first list and retrieve the corresponding item in the second one, using the dictionary. Here's an example, assuming you want to compare items with an ID property:

```
Dim DictB = ListB.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.ID)
For each itemA in ListA
    If DictB.ContainsKey(itemA.ID)
        'Item is in both lists
        Dim itemB = DictB(itemA.ID)
        'Do something here
    End If
Next
```